# How to get value of Input object in a Route Filter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've been following the Laravel guides in their website, but there's one thing that it's not clear to me. In the tutorial they describe this filter:

```
Route::filter('old', function() {
    if (Input::get('age') < 200) {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
});
```

What is the value of `Input` how does it get assigned?

The Route using that filter is not very descriptive:

```
Route::get('user', array('before' => 'old', function() {
    return 'You are over 200 years old!';
}));
```

My guess is that `Input` represents the user, but how does it get assigned? He's not fetching the user from the DB, nor anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ´Input´ (pretty much) always come from a form the user posted on your page. In this case you should have an input field named 'age' on it.

Take a look at requests and inputs: [Laravel 4 Requests & Input](http://four.laravel.com/docs/requests)

A form example for it, written in Laravel Blade:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
    {{ Form::text('name') }}
    {{ Form::text('age') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Submit this form') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

As soon as you submit this form you will be able to:

```
echo Input::get('name');
echo Input::get('age');
```

or just everything you submited:

```
var_dump(Input::all());
```

Comment: Input can also come from something like ajax data. i.e. `$.get('some/path', {age: 20}, function(){});`, you would retrieve the age data with `Input::get('age')`